# Android text view not found during execution time

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a text view that has to be updated on execution time. This text view is defined by the following xml:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/agi_val"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView" />
```

In the activity code, i acces to this (and other TextViews) like this:

```
private TextView AGI;
///< Some stuff

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_abf__char_gen__basic_info);

        abfToolsSaveData = (ABFToolsSaveData) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("SaveDataClass");

        this.AGI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.agi_val);
        ///< Some stuff

        if (abfToolsSaveData != null) {
            this.chargeData(true);
        } else {
            Log.d("INFO", "abfToolsSaveData is null");
        }
    }
```

And then, in chargeData(boolean):

```
public void chargeData(boolean firstTime){
        if(firstTime){
            MainCharacteristics mc = abfToolsSaveData.getCharacter().getMainCharacteristics(); ///< We get the main characteristics, auto-generated the first time

            /**
             * Set the Text Views with the default value
             */
            if(AGI != null){    ///< I've done this to check if the text view is null or not
                Log.d("INFO", String.valueOf(AGI));
                AGI.setText(mc.getAGI());
            }
            else
                Log.d("INFO","AGI IS NULL");
            ///< Some stuff
        }
    }
```

The thing is that the "agi_val" textview is being found, but the AGI textview of the activity, that i had saved before, it can't acces the resource "agi_val" whose linked. The error log is the following:

```
///< This first line shows the value of the "agi_val" ID. As you can see, it's not null.
    09-20 10:07:32.344 1266-1266/com.noeselmastersonlosdados.sliferdragon.penandpapercompanion D/INFO: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{b670993 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0d0077 app:id/agi_val}
    09-20 10:07:32.344 1266-1266/com.noeselmastersonlosdados.sliferdragon.penandpapercompanion W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000009
    --------- beginning of crash
    09-20 10:07:32.347 1266-1266/com.noeselmastersonlosdados.sliferdragon.penandpapercompanion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.noeselmastersonlosdados.sliferdragon.penandpapercompanion, PID: 1266
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.noeselmastersonlosdados.sliferdragon.penandpapercompanion/com.noeselmastersonlosdados.sliferdragon.penandpapercompanion.ABF_CharGen_BasicInfo}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x9
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x9
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4132)
///< This line is the assigment of the text
    at com.noeselmastersonlosdados.sliferdragon.penandpapercompanion.ABF_CharGen_BasicInfo.chargeData(ABF_CharGen_BasicInfo.java:73)
    at com.noeselmastersonlosdados.sliferdragon.penandpapercompanion.ABF_CharGen_BasicInfo.onCreate(ABF_CharGen_BasicInfo.java:54)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Someone knows what the hell is happening? I've been two days trying to solve this and I don't know how (i've searched on internet, but i can't find something similar).

If someone asks for the R class ID, its the same as show on the first line in the log.

Comment: try to **clean** and **rebuild** project

Comment: I've done that almost ten times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i've asked this same answer in "Stack Overflow en Español" and i get the answer.

The thing is that the `mc.getAGI()` is returning an int, so is using the override of `setText(int resourceId)`, that finds the resource `R.string` that has the `id` value.

Link to the answer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/103616/6568

Answer (score 0):

Once **setContentView()** has been called, you will never get a null View provided you are looking in the correct layout and the View exists in that layout.

You will only get a null if you're looking for a View by passing the wrong ID

**use this** `if (!AGI.getText().toString.matches(""))`

**or this**

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(AGI.getText().toString))
```

**insted of** `if(AGI != null)`

Comment: Thanks for this, this does not solves the problem, but it's usefull to know a new thing!

Comment: most welcome @SliferDragon if it help you can accept my ans

Comment: didn't get you..?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use `this` to reference to find `TextView` widget id in XML.

So, simply do this:

```
TextView AGI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.agi_val);
```

You can check the value is empty or not via **[isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty())** function too. You have to check null value of `abfToolsSaveData` not `AGI`. Check the type of `abfToolsSaveData` also. If it `integer` or `double`, then you have to parse the `integer/double` value to `string`.

```
if(!abfToolsSaveData.isEmpty()){
    AGI.setText("Some Text");
    //AGI.setText(String.valueOf("some integer content"));

}else {

}
```